# Android WebView Video Player Not displaying the Video for dynamic URL?

Tags: android, video, webview, html5-video

I have developed a webview HTML video player for my application. by using a single video tag i have appended multiple videos.All the video tag fields are set with the default video posters But if i click the video tag it doesn't work and simply getting a loader in video tag.
I din't get any error. hardware acceleration and internet-access are all i mentioned in my mainfest file. I'm clearly missing something obvious.. but I have no clue what. thank's to you.

```
    package com.example.androidtablayout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.drm.DrmErrorEvent;
import android.drm.DrmManagerClient;
import android.drm.DrmManagerClient.OnErrorListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class Feed extends index {


    private static final String TAG = null;
    private WebView mWebView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.photos_layout);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new chromeClient());
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        });
        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/homescreen.html");
    }


        public class chromeClient extends WebChromeClient implements OnCompletionListener,  
        OnErrorListener{
            private WebView wv;
            private VideoView mVideoView;
            private LinearLayout mContentView;
            private FrameLayout mCustomViewContainer;
            private WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback mCustomViewCallback;
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams COVER_SCREEN_GRAVITY_CENTER = new   
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER);

            @Override
            public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
                if (view instanceof FrameLayout) {
                    wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
                    mCustomViewContainer = (FrameLayout) view;
                    mCustomViewCallback = callback;
                    mContentView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
                    if (mCustomViewContainer.getFocusedChild() instanceof VideoView) {
                        mVideoView = (VideoView) mCustomViewContainer.getFocusedChild();
                       // frame.removeView(video);
                        mContentView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        setContentView(mCustomViewContainer);
                        mVideoView.setOnCompletionListener(this);
                        mVideoView.setOnErrorListener((android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener) this);
                        mVideoView.start();

                    }
                }
            }

            public void onHideCustomView() {
                if (mVideoView == null){
                    return;
                }else{
                // Hide the custom view.
                mVideoView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                // Remove the custom view from its container.
                mCustomViewContainer.removeView(mVideoView);
                mVideoView = null;
                mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
                // Show the content view.
                mContentView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }


            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.stop();
                mCustomViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                onHideCustomView();
                setContentView(mContentView);
            }

            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
                setContentView(mContentView);
                return true;
            }



            @Override
            public void onError(DrmManagerClient client, DrmErrorEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }


               public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                    mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();
                }


        }




    }
```

my layout xml file is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <!-- Screen Design for Photos -->



      <WebView  
  android:id="@+id/webview"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>
          <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"  />

    <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
```

Html video tag

```
<video id="example_video_1"  loop="true" width="340" height="264" ><source src="'+item.video_name'+"  /></video></div>
```